# Pandas Sort 2 columns with NaN condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new data frame with sort `Rank cur.`, while `Rank prev.` equal `NaN`

The point is to get All Current Rank where it didn't have Previous rank, while sorting current rank

Dataframe as following:

| Searchterm | Rank cur. | Rank prev. | Change | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Word1 | 5 | 29 | ↑ -28 | 20 |
| Word2 | 3 | NaN | ↑ -5 | 500 |
| Word3 | 2 | 9 | ↑ -6 | 35 |
| Word4 | 4 | NaN | ↑ -4 | 40 |
| Word5 | 1 | NaN | ↑ -6 | 210 |

My approach:
Where `dfMerged` is the original df

 *Note that the code works, but it get Volume value set to NaN (I would like to keep it-"at
same or at extra step")

```py
dfTopNewcomer = dfMerged[dfMerged['Rank prev.'].isnull()]
dfTopNewcomer = dfTopNewcomer.drop(['Rank prev.'], 1)
dfTopNewcomer = dfTopNewcomer.sort_values(by=['Rank cur.'], ascending=True)
dfTopNewcomer
```

The output i need should be:

```
Searchterm  Rank cur.   Rank prev.  Change      Volume
Word5           1           NaN         ↑ -6        210
Word3           2           NaN         ↑ -6        35
Word1           5           NaN         ↑ -28       20
```

Comment: It's not clear what the output of your program is? What doesn't work? `Volume` columns are `NaN`?

Comment: Yes, `Volume` columns are `NaN`
Everything else back as needed but not `volume`

Answer (score 0):

```
   df = dfMerged[dfMerged['Rank prev.'].isnull()].sort_values(by=['Rank cur.'])
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you!
My error was "simply" an error in previous step of `merge` 
Just fixing the merge and some of the data should be NaN (should be expected but slipped out)
Thank you for taking the time to help out!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can figure to get your desired output is by shifting the `Rank prev.` column...

```
dfTopNewcomer = dfMerged[dfMerged['Rank prev.'].shift(1).isnull()]
dfTopNewcomer = dfTopNewcomer.drop(['Rank prev.'], axis=1)
dfTopNewcomer = dfTopNewcomer.sort_values(by=['Rank cur.'], ascending=True)
print(dfTopNewcomer)
```

Output:

```
  Searchterm  Rank cur. Change  Volume
4      Word5          1   ↑ -6     210
2      Word3          2   ↑ -6      35
0      Word1          5  ↑ -28      20
```

Comment: Thank you!
My error was "simply" an error in previous step of `merge` 
All 3 codes in questions, answers works , `shift(1)` not recommended as it will mess up the df

Thank you for taking the time to help out!